# SPDY protocol not present/working - Updated

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, protocol

Google has released a new faster protocol as [SPDY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPDY). As Google says, it is enabled on google.com , somewhere I read that it is enabled only on encrypted/secure pages. There is a [Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/spdy-indicator/mpbpobfflnpcgagjijhmgnchggcjblin?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon) present that tells if the webpage is SPDY enabled or not.

I tested this on with Google.com and many other pages, in all the cases it showed `This website is NOT SPDY enabled`. I could understand that websites except of Google.com are not SPDY enabled, but even google.com is not SPDY enabled. I am using <strike>`Chrome 22.0.1229.91 beta-m`</strike>.`23.0.1271.10 beta-m`. I also tried checking it with Chrome internal URL but it also doesn't displays up Google using SPDY.

`chrome://net-internals/#events&q=type:SPDY_SESSION%20is:active`

[image: SPDY]

As far as I know *http**s**://google.com* should be SPDY enabled but it is not. Is this a problem with my copy of Chrome or is this the case with everyone. If this is the problem with my copy of Chrome then how to solve it?

**Update 1**: I am now using Chrome 23 Beta, earlier I was using Chrome 22 Beta and [someone commented](https://superuser.com/questions/482362/spdy-protocol-not-present-working#comment571610_482362) that Chrome 22 Stable is out, Oh yes it was out but Chrome 23 was not yet built and was not yet pushed as an update to Beta Channel users.

**Note 1/Update 2**: I recently installed Windows 8 Pro RTM (MSDN copy) and installed Chrome **Beta** on it, installed the same extension and it works over here. It shows that secure pages on Google.com are SPDY enabled. What can be the problem over there (Win 7)?

Comment: I am going to guess it has something to do with the fact your using a beta version of Chrome.  The current version is Chrome 22, not sure the reason your using a beta version of a browser, for which one has already been released.

Comment: I don't check of the current stable as I use beta and canary builds. Chrome 22 is released just now (max 1 week, I guess), and beta for Chrome 23 is not yet built so is not pushed as an update to beta users. Chrome still shows this as the most up-to-date version in beta channel. Also while the beta for next version is not pushed the users of beta channel use Stable build until the next beta is pushed.

Comment: I would still blame this on the fact your using a beta channel build.  Come back after you have tried the release build.

Comment: Ok, then Let me try this on `Stable`, `Dev` and `Canary` Channels also.

Comment: @Ramhound I have tried this on all the Channels (Multiple copies of Chrome running on same machine) but it still doesn't shows up the desired result.